# Cleaning a column in Pandas - Gibberish

Tags: pandas, for-loop, lambda, nltk

**Purpose**: To clean OneCol column in my pandas data frame.
**What I did**: I imported NLTK, and ran this code:

```
import nltk    
import collections
from nltk.corpus import words

for value in df_US['OneCol']:
    if value in words.words():
        df_US['Result']=df_US['Result'].iloc.append(value)
```

I tried this one too:

```
#df_US['Result'] = df_US[['OneCol']].apply(lambda x: x.words.words())
```

No success!

My data looks like this:

[image]

Thank you, I appreciate any advice you can give me.

Comment: share your dataframe `df_US`

Comment: instead of sharing a screenshot, please share the dataframe in code

Comment: What would be the expected result for provided values - "good", "xxxx" and "i like to code"?

Comment: Hi Alexandra, I would like to delete those people typing invalid words/gibberish. In this case code 2, xxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define a test dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,2,3, 4],
    'Country': [2,2,2,2],
    'Q1': ['', '', 'I like to CODE', ''],
    'Q2': ['Good', 'xxxx', '', 'some gibberish text: jgsldkgnlk'],
    'OneCol': ['good', 'xxxx', 'i like to code', 'some gibberish text: jgsldkgnlk']
})
df
```

That will give following dataframe:
[image: Dataframe]

```
import nltk    
import collections
from nltk.corpus import words
nltk.download('words')

df['Result'] = df['OneCol'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(list(set(x.split()) & set(words.words()))))

df
```

That will give following result (removes unknown words):
[image: Dataframe]

If you want to remove field in case it contains at least one unknown word, following approach can be used:

```
df['Result'] = df['OneCol'].apply(lambda x: x if len(list(set(x.split()) & set(words.words()))) == len(set(x.split())) else None)
```

That will give following result (removes field if it contains unknown words):
[image: Dataframe]

Please note, that this logic doesn't consider punctuation marks. If text will contain punctuation, words next to the punctuation marks will not be recognised.

Comment: Thank you, Alexandra, much appreciated! I will look into it. I cleaned my text from punctuation and numbers.

Comment: Hi Alexandra, thank you very much for this! It works great. What if I cant to return the values True or False, instead of the strings?

Comment: To get boolean value in `Result` column following expression can be used: `df['Result'] = df['OneCol'].apply(lambda x: len(list(set(x.split()) & set(words.words()))) == len(set(x.split())))`